# python - how to create dictionary of dictionary in loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, graph

I am trying to generate a graph of cities from a file.
Each `readline()` I am getting three values, `a`, `b`, and `c`.
`a` and `b` are strings, names of cities, and `c` is an `int`, the path cost between `a` and `b`.
How can I store `a`,`b`,`c` so that I get something like

```
graph = {
          'a1': {'b1': c1, 'b1': 5, 'a2': c2},
          'a2': {'a1': c2},
          'b1': {'a1': c1},
        }
```

Here is part of my code:

```
dict = dict()   #dictionary for storing values
while (True):
    new_path = file.readline()
    if new_path == "":
        break
    new_path = new_path.rstrip().split(", ")
    a = new_path[0][2:len(new_path[0]) - 1] #start town
    b = new_path[1][1:len(new_path[1]) - 1] #end town
    c = new_path[2][0:len(new_path[2]) - 1] #path cost
    print(a+" "+b+" "+c)   #this prints Arlington Chelmsford 4
```

.......
  Since I don't know if the key is already in the dictionary, I have tried adding the key with empty value if key is not in `dict.keys()`, but then `update()` will function weirdly and give me some sort of list.
  I am new to python so please explain to me how to create such a graph that doesn't include any `[]` symbol in. Thanks a million!!

the final result I want would be something like this:

`{'Arlington': {'Chelmsford': 4, 'Berkshire': 10}, 'Chelmsford': {'Arlington': 4, 'Berkshire': 5}, 'Berkshire': {'Arlington': 10, 'Chelmsford': 5}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following loop that sets the `graph` dict in both directions:

```
graph = {}
for line in file:
    a, b, c = line.rstrip().split(', ')
    graph.setdefault(a, {})[b] = c
    graph.setdefault(b, {})[a] = c
```

so that given file content:

```
Arlington, Chelmsford, 4
Arlington, Berkshire, 10
Chelmsford, Berkshire, 5
```

`graph` would become:

`{'Arlington': {'Chelmsford': '4', 'Berkshire': '10'}, 'Chelmsford': {'Arlington': '4', 'Berkshire': '5'}, 'Berkshire': {'Arlington': '10', 'Chelmsford': '5'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example leveraging the built-in libraries.  `defaultdict` makes sure if a key is not already present in the dictionary it is created with default value...in this case, an empty dictionary.  The `csv` module can be used to read and parse comma-separated input.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

D = defaultdict(dict)

with open('input.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for a,b,c in r:
        D[a][b] = int(c)
        D[b][a] = int(c)

print(dict(D)) # dict() is unnecessary, but prints better than the defaultdict object
```

Input:

```
Arlington,Chelmsford,4
Arlington,Berkshire,10
Chelmsford,Berkshire,5
```

Output:

```
{'Arlington': {'Chelmsford': 4, 'Berkshire': 10}, 'Chelmsford': {'Arlington': 4, 'Berkshire': 5}, 'Berkshire': {'Arlington': 10, 'Chelmsford': 5}}
```